# How to delete multiple values inside given pandas dataframe when groupby and transform is used?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was calculating mean,min,stddeviation of azimuth and distance.The sample data(df2) is below:
sim_Az varies from **-55 to 55** with a stepsize = 5

| Sim_Az | Sim_dist | RUT_Azi | RUT_Dist | Mean_dist | Min_dist | Mean_azi | Min_azi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.85 | 4.38 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.95 | 4.35 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.38 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.98 | 4.35 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.96 | 4.35 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 7.38 | -55.86 | 7.45 | 7.43 | 7.41 | -55.91 | -55.99 |
| -55 | 7.38 | -55.87 | 7.46 | 7.43 | 7.41 | -55.91 | -55.99 |

The expected output is:

| Sim_Az | Sim_dist | RUT_Azi | RUT_Dist | Mean_dist | Min_dist | Mean_azi | Min_azi | count | percent missed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.85 | 4.38 | 4.34 | 4.33 | -55.91 | -55.99 | 9 | 91 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.37 | 7.43 | 7.41 | -55.91 | -55.99 | 2 | 98 |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.95 | 4.35 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.86 | 4.38 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.98 | 4.35 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.84 | 4.37 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 3.38 | -55.96 | 4.35 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 7.38 | -55.86 | 7.45 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -55 | 7.38 | -55.87 | 7.46 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The code i used to get the sample data:

```
df2['Mean_dist'] = df2.groupby(['Sim_Az','Sim_dist'])['RUT_Dist'].transform('mean') 
df2['Min_dist'] = df2.groupby(['Sim_Az_','Sim_dist'])['RUT_Dist'].transform('min')
df2['Mean_Azi'] = df2.groupby(['Sim_Az','Sim_dist'])['RUT_Azi'].transform('mean') 
df2['Min_Azi'] = df2.groupby(['Sim_Az_','Sim_dist'])['RUT_Azi'].transform('min')
```

Try1:When i tried to use aggregate i got an error(TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index)

```
df2['Mean_dist'] = df2.groupby(['Sim_Az','Sim_dist'])['RUT_Dist'].agg('mean')
```

How to avoid the duplicate entries from Mean_dist to Min_azi and get an expected output as given ?
How can i add columns *count,percent missed* to sample data?
The count is based on the number of multiple sim_dist and the percent is 100-count

Comment: You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).  `drop_duplicates(subset=list(df2.columns[-5:-1]))`.

Comment: @Rawson for example the same values are repeating for  sim_Az = 55.so deleting the duplicates will delete those values also

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment before, `drop_duplicates()` removed those rows, which was now what you wanted.  Instead you can use [`mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) (or `where()`):

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
df
#    Sim_Az  Sim_dist  RUT_Azi  RUT_Dist  Mean_dist  Min_dist  Mean_azi  Min_azi
#0      -55      3.38   -55.85      4.38       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#1      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.37       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#2      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#3      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#4      -55      3.38   -55.95      4.35       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#5      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.38       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#6      -55      3.38   -55.98      4.35       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#7      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#8      -55      3.38   -55.96      4.35       4.34      4.33    -55.91   -55.99
#9      -55      7.38   -55.86      7.45       7.43      7.41    -55.91   -55.99
#10     -55      7.38   -55.87      7.46       7.43      7.41    -55.91   -55.99
```

Calculations:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby("Sim_dist")["Sim_dist"].transform("count")
df["percent_missed"] = 100 - df["count"]
df[list(df.columns[-6:])] = df[list(df.columns[-6:])].mask(df[list(df.columns[-6:])].duplicated(),"")
df
#    Sim_Az  Sim_dist  RUT_Azi  RUT_Dist Mean_dist Min_dist Mean_azi Min_azi count percent_missed
#0      -55      3.38   -55.85      4.38      4.34     4.33   -55.91  -55.99     9             91
#1      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.37                                                         
#2      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#3      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#4      -55      3.38   -55.95      4.35                                                         
#5      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.38                                                         
#6      -55      3.38   -55.98      4.35                                                         
#7      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#8      -55      3.38   -55.96      4.35                                                         
#9      -55      7.38   -55.86      7.45      7.43     7.41   -55.91  -55.99     2             98
#10     -55      7.38   -55.87      7.46
```

This can be broken down to make it clearer:

1. `count` and `percent_missed` columns created first (which must then also be duplicates, so will also be removed).
2. `list(df.columns[-6:])` is the list of the columns that contain the duplicates (the last 6 columns, including `count` and `percent_missed`)
3. `df[list(df.columns[-6:])]` returns the dataframe with those columns only.
4. `df[list(df.columns[-6:])].duplicated()` returns a Boolean series of as to whether all columns are a duplicate of another row before it (so every single column must be the same).
5. `df.mask(condition, other)` replaces values with `other` anytime the condition is `True`.

I realise the output is slightly different, but this is so that the other columns also align.  I'm not sure it makes sense to change `Sim_dist` from 7.38 to 3.38 for the second row of not-deleted duplicates.

If, however, this is how you want to do it, you can use `drop_duplicates()` in a copy of the dataframe, then merge the first columns (`:-4`) of the first dataframe with the last columns (`-6:`) of the second:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2["count"] = df2.groupby("Sim_dist")["Sim_dist"].transform("count")
df2["percent_missed"] = 100 - df2["count"]
df2 = df2.iloc[:, -6:].drop_duplicates().reset_index()

df3 = df.iloc[:, :-4].merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer").drop(columns=["index"]).fillna("")
df3
#    Sim_Az  Sim_dist  RUT_Azi  RUT_Dist Mean_dist Min_dist Mean_azi Min_azi count percent_missed
#0      -55      3.38   -55.85      4.38      4.34     4.33   -55.91  -55.99   9.0           91.0
#1      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.37      7.43     7.41   -55.91  -55.99   2.0           98.0
#2      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#3      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#4      -55      3.38   -55.95      4.35                                                         
#5      -55      3.38   -55.86      4.38                                                         
#6      -55      3.38   -55.98      4.35                                                         
#7      -55      3.38   -55.84      4.37                                                         
#8      -55      3.38   -55.96      4.35                                                         
#9      -55      7.38   -55.86      7.45                                                         
#10     -55      7.38   -55.87      7.46
```

- This assumes you have not named your index at all (and it has been reset, if not, then use `df.reset_index().iloc[:, :-4]` in the last line).